# bonuses from implements to effect besides dmg?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements

I was wondering if implement bonuses also apply to temporary hit points gained from a power's effect. So for example I do an attack that does 1d8 + [ability] damage (so 1d8 + [ability modifier] + [implement bonus] dmg). On hit this power has a secondary effect. It grands [ability modifier] temporary hit points.
Now my question: Does the [implement bonus] also apply for the temporary hit points gained though this power??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, then Enhancement Bonus of a magic item (weapon or implement) is only added to attack and damage rolls.

> For items that give an enhancement bonus, this entry specifies what
>   **that bonus applies to: AC, other defenses, or attack rolls and damage
>   rolls. Magic weapons and implements grant their enhancement bonus to
>   attack rolls and damage rolls** only when you use powers delivered
>   through the weapon or the implement (or directly from the weapon or
>   the implement, for items that have attack powers).

PHB page 225

If it has a property that increases Temporary Hit Points, that's another thing.